# How to connect mysql from a file written in C which contains native methods of java?

Tags: java, mysql, c, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I need some way to connect MySQL with C which have Java JNI methods in it.
I made a Java file which calls a native method written in C which needs to be connected to MySQL database.

**C File**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <mysql/mysql.h>
 #include "MyClass.h"
 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_pkg_MyClass_display(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
     return  (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,mysql_get_client_info());
 }
```

**Java File**

```
public class MyClass {
public native String display();
public static String Disp(){
    MyClass ob = new MyClass();
    String str =  ob.display();
    return str;
     }
static {
    System.load("Desktop/libdemo.so");
}
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(Disp());
   }
}
```

After creating shared object library (**.so**), an error occurs:

```
undefined reference to : mysql_get_client_info()
```

Please suggest some way to rectify this problem.

Comment: what's wrong wtih JDBC?

Comment: as far as i know jdbc is to connect database with java..i need to connect it with c file as i am creating .so

Comment: "i need to connect it with c file" - right, but _why_?

Comment: I need to develop a UI for FPGA which needs .so file to interact with the hardware. For making the UI i chose to use JAVA. I accept the data using Java and send it to the c file using native methods. This data in turn should be stored in the database. According to me i will need to connect the database with C. Please suggest if some other way is possible.

Comment: "as far as i know jdbc is to connect database with java." exactly. you are dead right.

Comment: What the questions are getting at is why do you feel you need to use C to talk to the database when it can be easily done from Java?

Comment: Have you installed the libmysql-dev library ?